# Using python for decoding url content

Tags: python

There is a site which contains bible translations in Greek and Hebrew in Russian.

Here is python2 code for getting url content:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import io, urllib

f1 = io.open('url.txt','w',encoding='utf8')
#link = "http://manuscript-bible.ru/OT/Gen1.htm"
link = "http://manuscript-bible.ru/S/H/psa117.htm"
f2 = urllib.urlopen(link)
myfile = f2.read().decode("utf-8")
f1.write(myfile)
f1.close()
```

Thus,for Hebrew and Russian using `f2.read().decode("utf-8")` it is possible to get the url from http://manuscript-bible.ru/S/H/psa117.htm e.g.:

```
>1</strong>
<a target="_blank" href="../S/h19.htm#1984" title="hалэлу">הַֽלְלוּ</a>
<a target="_blank" href="../S/h08.htm#853" title="ʼэт">אֶת</a>
```

for Russian as well it is possible to get the content using  `myfile = f2.read().decode('cp1251')` from http://manuscript-bible.ru/RSV/22_116.htm
here one sentence of the content `.htm`

```
<b>1</b> Хвалите
<01984> Господа
    <03068>, все народы
        <01471>, прославляйте
            <07623> Его, все племена
                <0523>;
```

The problem is with this url http://manuscript-bible.ru/OT/Ps116.htm which is not possible to decode:
by inspection from the source of `.htm` it seems that there is two  `Gen1.htm` with the same extension `.htm`
and one of them contain something like:

```
anot=0;bn=22;cn=116;variants="";cr=new Array();parsing="";a=new Array("","","","","","","","
<a name=116>","","","","
    <br>","","","","
    <br>","CALMOI","calmoi","6163","\u041F\u0421\u0410\u041B\u041C\u042B","\u0413\u043B\u0430\u0432\u0430 116","","","","","","","
    <br>","","","","
    <br>","","","","","1","","","","Allhlouia.","allhlouia","6C61","\u0410\u043B\u043B\u0438\u043B\u0443\u0439\u044F.","A\u042Ene\u042Dte","a\u042Ene\u042Dte","6961","\u0425\u0432\u0430\u043B\u0438&#769\u0442\u0435","t\u0442n","t\u0441n","6F74","-","k\u0436rion,","k\u0436rion","756B","\u0413\u043E&#769\u0441\u043F\u043E\u0434\u0430,"
```

it seems that is `utf-16` coding because when inserted in https://www.branah.com/unicode-converter
we get:

```
anot=0;bn=22;cn=116;variants="";cr=new Array();parsing="";a=new 

Array("","","","","","","","
<a name=116>","","","","
    <br>","","","","
    <br>","CALMOI","calmoi","6163","ПСАЛМЫ","Глава 116","","","","","","","
    <br>","","","","
    <br>","","","","","1","","","","Allhlouia.","allhlouia","6C61","Аллилуйя.","AЮneЭte","aЮneЭte","6961","Хвали&#769те","tтn","tсn","6F74","-","kжrion,","kжrion","756B","Го&#769спода,"
```

The question is, how to get the decoded content of mentioned url http://manuscript-bible.ru/OT/Ps116.htm, using python like code above?

Comment: Those are valid Unicode code points and don't necessarily need to be converted. Python understands them. If you print that to screen it should display fine.

Comment: There also appear to be HTML entities in there (e.g., `&#769`). Quick example showing what I mean for the encoding and for the HTML entities: https://python-fiddle.com/saved/LuacORSFGhZ6lhHg89Jt